# How do I remove old x86 File Association if Replaced with 64 bit program with the same name?

Tags: notepad++, file-association

I originally had x86 Notepad++ and made it my opening program for a lot of file types..

I then switched to 64-bit Notepad ++, but now my file associations look like this.

[image]

Is their any way to remove the Old 32-bit association from this list from all programs that I might have given this association to, but keep the new 64-bit association?

Comment: I had a similar issue when upgrading from x86 office to x64 once and was satisfied with changing file associations with the cmd assoc and ftype commands. I believe the help pages for these will also show you how to list the existing associations, same as are queried in the GUI. It’s not EXACTLY what you asked but it may be a more practical solution. There may be knock-on effects... I remember x64 office icons didn’t display properly... but take notes before changing associations and you can always return precious settings. Not hard to fix icons, I just didn’t.

Comment: Maybe change all the associations to good'ole Notepad, reboot and change them to NP++ in NP++ preferences?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to reinstall the 32-bit version and uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/). Revo will clean up the registry for you.